# How remove min value in mongodb for group?

Tags: mongodb

I am beginner with mongodb.

I need to remove min price for each store.

the document(products):

input:

```
product_id|store_id|price|color|
--------------------------------
1         |   1    | 10  |red
2         |   1    | 9   |blue
3         |   1    | 12  |red
4         |   2    | 19  |red
5         |   2    | 20  |red
6         |   2    | -1  |red
7         |   6    | 30  |red
8         |   6    | 10  |blue
```

output:

```
product_id|store_id|price|color|
--------------------------------
2         |   1    | 9   |blue
3         |   1    | 12  |red
4         |   2    | 19  |red
5         |   2    | 20  |red
8         |   6    | 10  |blue
```

I write this code in my.js

```
use stores;
var products=db.products.distinct('product_id');
for(i=0; i<products.length; i++){
   db.products.remove({product_id:i,color:'red'}).sort({price:1}).limit(1);
}
```

But my code not works,Please write better code or show my mistake/

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try:

```
// this returns an array of documents which has the store_id and the minimum price for that store
myresult = db.products.aggregate( [ 
                            { $group: 
                                 { _id: "$store_id", 
                                   price: { $min: "$price" } 
                                 } 
                            } 
                            ] ).result

// loop through the results to remove the documents matching the the store id and price

for (i in myresult) { 
    db.products.remove( 
         { store_id: myresult[i]._id, price: myresult[i].price } 
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove from each store the lowest priced item? or just the lowest priced item that has the color 'red'?  My query was for the first, but it's easy enough to modify to include color red: myresult = db.products.aggregate( [ {$match: { color:"red" }},{ $group: { _id: "$store_id", price: { $min: "$price" } } } ] ).result      and then for (i in myresult) { db.products.remove( { store_id: myresult[i]._id, price: myresult[i].price, color: "red" } ); }

Comment: "I need to remove min price for each store." ?? Explain your question precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost right, just needs a few modifications:

```
use stores;
var products = db.products.distinct('product_id');
products.forEach(function(i, v){
    var id = db.products.find({product_id: v, color: "red"}).sort({price: 1}).limit(1).toArray()[0];
    db.products.remove({_id: id._id}); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To me your code seems fine. Just wondering you want to find by store_id and then remove minimum price product based on the color.

There is a direct way in mongodb **findAndModify()** which finds and modifies single document by default.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#findandmodify-wrapper-sorted-remove

```
var products=db.products.distinct('store_id');
products.forEach(function(storeId, i){
    db.products.findAndModify({
        query: { "store_id":storeId, "color": "red" }, 
        sort: { price:  1 }, 
        remove: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for some one who search as "How to remove min value in mongodb?"

```
var myresult = db.mycol.aggregate
([{
    $group:
    {
       _id:"",
       agevalue: { $min: "$age" }
    }
   
}]);
db.mycol.remove( {"age": myresult._batch[0].agevalue})
```

You can assign column name to the `_id`. Then query will group the results according to that column. Then you can have multiple min values for each group.